# contextvars утечка памяти

Tags: python, python-3.x, context

Разбираюсь с пакетом `contextvars`. Увидел комментарий в [документации](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/contextvars.html):

> Important: Context Variables should be created at the top module level
> and never in closures. Context objects hold strong references to
> context variables which prevents context variables from being properly
> garbage collected.

Что понимается под использованием в верху модуля? Нельзя использовать внутрии функции? Означает ли это, что я могу поймать утчеку памяти? Что это означает?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В целом да, нельзя создавать `contextvars` внутри функций, разве что в мейне.

Суть в том что текущий тред ссылается на `Context` object, а `Context` держит ссылки на `contextvars`. Соответственно пока жив тред - жив и контекст со всеми его `contextvars`.

На этом примере видно, что `contextvars` не удаляются, хотя мы вышли их контекста фцнкции:

```
In [2]: import contextvars

In [3]: def foo():
   ...:     var = contextvars.ContextVar("var")
   ...:     var.set(0)
   ...:     print(var, var.get())
   ...:

In [4]: foo()
<ContextVar name='var' at 0x10e222fc0> 0

In [5]: foo()
<ContextVar name='var' at 0x10e1fb308> 0

In [6]: foo()
<ContextVar name='var' at 0x10e1fb6d0> 0

In [7]: list(contextvars.copy_context().items())
Out[7]:
[(<ContextVar name='var' at 0x10e1fb308>, 0),
 (<ContextVar name='var' at 0x10e222fc0>, 0),
 (<ContextVar name='var' at 0x10e1fb6d0>, 0)]
```

Но если запустить функцию в треде (т.е в другом контексте), то по завершению этого треда, контекст будет очищен:

```
In [9]: from threading import Thread

In [10]: len(contextvars.copy_context())
Out[10]: 3

In [11]: Thread(target=foo).start()
<ContextVar name='var' at 0x10e24ef68> 0

In [12]: len(contextvars.copy_context())
Out[12]: 3
```

Подробнее про реализацию можно почитать [тут](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0567/#implementation).